Searchable Combobox how to avoid gap between lightning-input and listbox

I have developed a searchable combobox as a LWC and everything is working fine, except that there is a little gap between the lightning-input component and the listbox. What do I need to do, do get rid of the gap?

Here comes the HTML of the component:
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" id="combobox-label-id-130" for="combobox-122">
            <abbr if:true={required} class="slds-required" title="required">*</abbr>
            {label}
        </label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning-input
                    id="combobox-122"
                    class="inputField"
                    label={label}
                    type="search"
                    variant="label-hidden"
                    onfocus={handleOnFocus}
                    onchange={handleChange}
                    onkeydown={handleKeyDown}
                    value={userInput}
                    onblur={handleBlur}
                    message-when-value-missing={messageWhenValueMissing}
                    message-when-too-long={messageWhenTooLong}
                    message-when-too-short={messageWhenTooShort}
                    min-length={minLength}
                    max-length={maxLength}
            ></lightning-input>
            <div if:true={hasSearchResults} class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid listbox" style="overflow: auto" tabindex="0"
                 role="listbox" onmousedown={handleComboboxMouseDown} onmouseup={handleComboboxMouseUp}>
                <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                    <template for:each={searchResults} for:item="searchResult">
                        <li key={searchResult.value}  role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                            <div class={searchResult.classes}
                                 data-value={searchResult.value}
                                 onclick={handleOptionSelected}
                                 role="option">
                                <span class="slds-media__body">
                                    <span class="slds-truncate" title={searchResult.label}>
                                        {searchResult.label}
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

And here the JavaScript:
import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
const CLS_LIST_ITEM = 'slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small';
const KEY_ARROW_UP = 38;
const KEY_ARROW_DOWN = 40;
const KEY_ENTER = 13;
const KEY_TAB = 9;
const KEY_ESC = 27;

export default class Combobox extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api required;
    @api options;
    @api messageWhenValueMissing = 'Please select or enter a value';
    @api messageWhenTooLong;
    @api messageWhenTooShort;
    @api name;
    @api minLength;
    @api maxLength;
    @api restricted = false;

    // template parameters
    searchResults = [];          // List of filtered options
    @track userInput = "";      // Input of the user

    // internal parameters
    _focusedResultIndex = null;    // if the list is navigated by keyboard the index of the item
    _cancelBlur = false;
    _picklistOrdered;                   // all picklist entries ordered by label
    _oldUserInput = "";          // input before last change event
    @track _selectedOption;             // if restricted, the selected option

    @api
    get value() {
        if ( this.restricted ) {
            // if we simulate a combobox, return the api value
            return this._selectedOption?.value;
        } else {
            return this.userInput;
        }
    }
    set value( newVal ) {
        if ( this.restricted ) {
            // if we simulate a combobox, set the option
            this._selectedOption = this._picklistOrdered.find(opt => opt.value === newVal );
            this.userInput = this._selectedOption.label;
        } else {
            // if it just a input with, set user input
            this.userInput = newVal;
        }
        this._oldUserInput = this.userInput;
    }

    get hasSearchResults() {
        return this.searchResults.length > 0;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        // order options alphabetically by label
        if ( this.options ) {
            this._picklistOrdered = this.options.map(obj => ({...obj}));
            this._picklistOrdered = this._picklistOrdered.sort((a, b)=>{
                if(a.label < b.label) {
                    return -1;
                } else if ( a.label > b.label ) {
                    return 1;
                } else return 0;
            })
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        // filter combobox
        const input = event.detail.value.toLowerCase();
        const result = this._picklistOrdered.filter((picklistOption) =>
            picklistOption.label.toLowerCase().includes(input)
        );
        this.userInput = event.detail.value;
        let inputField = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        if ( result.length === 0 ) {
            // if we simulate a combo box and the user input leads to no results, prevent input
            if ( this.restricted ) {
                this.userInput = this._oldUserInput;
                inputField.value = this._oldUserInput;
            } else {
                //hide listbox
                this.clearSearchResults();
            }
        } else {
            // refresh combobox selection
            this._focusedResultIndex = null;
            this.styleCombobox(result);
        }
        this._oldUserInput = this.userInput;

        // clear error message for custom validity
        if ( !inputField.validity.valid ) {
            inputField.setCustomValidity("");
            inputField.reportValidity();
        }

        // if we simulate a combobox, stop event propagation
        if ( this.restricted ) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    styleCombobox(result) {
        this.searchResults = result.map((result, i) => {
            // add slds-has-focus to the selected result for keyboard navigation
            let cls = CLS_LIST_ITEM + (this._focusedResultIndex === i ? ' slds-has-focus' : '');
            return {
                "label" : result.label,
                "value" : result.value,
                "classes" : cls
            };
        });
    }

    handleOptionSelected(event) {
        // get api value of selected option
        const selectedValue = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
        this._selectedOption = this._picklistOrdered.find(
            (picklistOption) => picklistOption.value === selectedValue
        );
        this.userInput = this._selectedOption.label;
        this._oldUserInput = this._selectedOption.label;
        // hide list box
        this.clearSearchResults();
        // notify parent component of the change
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change",
            {
                detail:
                    {
                        value   : this._selectedOption.label,
                        name    : this.name,
                        label   : this._selectedOption.label,
                        apiName : this._selectedOption.value
                    }
            }));
        this.reportValidity();
    }

    handleComboboxMouseDown(event) {
        this._cancelBlur = true;
    }
    handleComboboxMouseUp() {
        this._cancelBlur = false;
        // Re-focus to text input for the next blur event
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').focus();
    }

    clearSearchResults() {
        this.searchResults = [];
    }

    handleOnFocus() {
        this._focusedResultIndex = null;
        // don't open listbox if the user returns and a value has already been selected
        if ( this._selectedOption ) return;
        if ( this.searchResults.length === 0) {
            this.styleCombobox(this._picklistOrdered)
        }
    }

    handleBlur( event ) {
        if ( this._cancelBlur ) {
            return;
        }
        let inputField = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        // Close search results if field is left
        this.clearSearchResults();

        // handle required message
        this.reportValidity();
    }

    handleKeyDown( event ) {
        console.log('--> Key Down ' + this._focusedResultIndex);
        if (this._focusedResultIndex === null) {
            this._focusedResultIndex = -1;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_ARROW_DOWN) {
            // If we hit 'down', select the next item, or cycle over.
            this._focusedResultIndex++;
            if (this._focusedResultIndex >= this.searchResults.length) {
                this._focusedResultIndex = 0;
            }
            this.scrollToSelectedItem();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_ARROW_UP) {
            // If we hit 'up', select the previous item, or cycle over.
            this._focusedResultIndex--;
            if (this._focusedResultIndex < 0) {
                this._focusedResultIndex = this.searchResults.length - 1;
            }
            this.scrollToSelectedItem()
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.keyCode === KEY_ENTER && this._focusedResultIndex >= 0 && this.hasSearchResults) {
            console.log('--> Enter ' + this._focusedResultIndex);
            // If the user presses enter, and the box is open, and we have used arrows,
            // treat this just like a click on the listbox item
            const selected = this.searchResults[this._focusedResultIndex].value;
            const li = this.template.querySelector(`[data-value="${selected}"]`);
            li.click();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ( event.keyCode === KEY_TAB && this.hasSearchResults ) {
            // if the user presses TAB close the list box and go to the next input
            this.clearSearchResults();
        } else if ( event.keyCode === KEY_ESC ) {
            // if the user presses ESC close the list box
            this.clearSearchResults();
        }
        this.styleCombobox(this.searchResults);
    }

    scrollToSelectedItem() {
        const selected = this.searchResults[this._focusedResultIndex].value;
        const li = this.template.querySelector(`[data-value="${selected}"]`);
        li.scrollIntoView(false);
    }

    @api
    reportValidity() {
        let inputField = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        if ( this.required && this.userInput === "") {
            inputField.setCustomValidity(this.messageWhenValueMissing);
        } else {
            inputField.setCustomValidity("");
        }
        return inputField.reportValidity();
    }

    @api
    checkValidity() {
        let inputField = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        if ( this.required && this.userInput === "") {
            return false;
        }
        return inputField.checkValidity();
    }
}

And the CSS:
.inputField {
    border : 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.listbox {
    padding-top: 0;
}

